# How to give a collection view section header dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with a section header that displays a users information. The header can include a bio from the user. I am having trouble with resizing the header if the bio is long. The label will not display the whole bio because the header stays at a fixed height.

I created the collection view via storyboard however I added the constraints programmatically.

Here is the bio constraints, I thought by setting the height and lines to 0 I would be okay,

```swift
      addSubview(bioLabel)
        bioLabel.anchor(top: editProfileButton.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 12, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 0)
```

I also thought I could override the storyboard by

```
    // Trying to override storyboard header height so the header can strech depending on the bio height
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        //TODO change height to be bounds.height of bioLabel?
        return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: 300)

    }
```

but it appears even if I try to change the size through code, it keeps the  storyboard height of 225 ( which is what I would like)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the answers given so far are good practices since calculating the size manually or by rendering a label offscreen are both inefficient and violate the single source of truth principle.

Instances of `UICollectionReusableView` have the `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting()` method. When the cell becomes displayed, this method will be called. In this method, if you use Auto Layout, you ask the whole cell for its `systemLayoutSizeFitting()` and then modify the attributes. The layout will then be responsible to apply them via layout invalidation.

Answer (score -1):

Use an instance of UICollectionReusableView to be your header. 
And calculate the actual size of header in this method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize { }
```

Make sure you header is ready for dynamic height as well. Good luck.

Comment: Let's do it from the xib file of your header or add constraints programmatically

Answer (score -1):

This function will do the work. Just pass the label text

```
func estimatedLabelHeight(text: String) -> CGFloat {

        let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 16, height: 1000)

        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)

        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)]

        let rectangleHeight = String(text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil).height

        return rectangleHeight
    }
```

And use it like

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        //TODO change height to be bounds.height of bioLabel?
        return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedLabelHeight(text: "Text that your label is gonna show"))

    }
```

Comment: Will the height still change even though the height is set in storyboard?

Comment: @Clint yes, try above code and let me know if it works.

Comment: For ```estimatedLabelHeight(text: "you label text"))``` Do I pass in the label there? or on ```let rectangleHeight = String(text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil).height```

Comment: @Clint you just need to pass the text which the label is gonna show i.e the String which you assigned to ```label.text```

Comment: Alright, did that. However the header size remains the same. As I mentioned I created the collection view / section header using storyboards. It keeps the storyboard height of 225. Can I override it some how?

Comment: @Clint you can change/override storyboard height by firstly linking your height constraint like ```@IBOutlet weak var headerHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!``` and later changing it like ```headerHeight.constant = estimatedLabelHeight(text: "Text that your label is gonna show")```. Let me know if you still faces any issue.

Comment: But I can't grab the height of the section header. Or I do not see the actual constraint for it. That is set in the size inspector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199668/discussion-between-deepak-verma-and-clint).

Answer (score -1):

**You can get Label Height using below function**

```
func heightForLabel(text: String, font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

  let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
  label.numberOfLines = 0
  label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
  label.font = font
  label.text = text
  label.sizeToFit()

  return label.frame.height
}
```

**Collection Header Method**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    let height = self.heightForLabel(text: 'your text', font: 'font which you in label' , width: 'your label width')
    return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: height+10) //10 is extra height if you want or you can remove it.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate the size of cell height in method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

 var size = CGSize()
            let cell = YourUICollectionViewCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = data?[indexPath.row].text
            let fitting = CGSize(width: cell.frame.size.width, height: 1)
            size = cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(fitting,
                                                            withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
                                                            verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority(1))
            return size.height //or just return size 

}
```

If UILabel is custom then you need to set the bottom Constraint of UILabel to view with less than 1000 priority.
Hope it helps